# Flow types for optional parameter in higher order React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to create a higher order component using Flow types, but am having trouble with the returned component type.

Minimal example:

```
/* @flow */

import React from 'react';

type Props = {
  name: string,
  what: number
}

const TestComponent = (props: Props) => null

function withDefaultClassname<Config: {}>(
  Component: React$AbstractComponent<Config, *>
): React$AbstractComponent<{...$Exact<Config>, name: string}, *> {
  return (props) => <Component {...props} className={props.className || 'default'} />;
}
const Wrapped2 = withDefaultClassname(TestComponent)

// $ExpectError - should complain about undefined props
const a = <Wrapped2 />
```

In the example above, the higher order component sets the `className` prop if it doesn't exist, otherwise uses the provided prop. Therefore, I've tried to set the return type of the higher order component to set `className` as an optional prop. Nevertheless, this seems to cause issues whereby otherwise required props are no longer enforced by Flow. Is there a better way to do this?

The Flow documentation [talks about injecting props](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/#toc-injecting-props), but that involves using the `$Diff` utility type. I'd like to indicate that the return type here does include `className` as an optional prop, making the `$Diff` utility type unhelpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`Config & {className?: string}` seems [to works correctly](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gFSgCGAzqAEoCmRAxnpFrKqAORbV0sDciiOAnukqgACo3RkAvKADeiUKAB2RVJQBcoEjizJFAcwA080PAAWRHBsUBXVACNKWRAF9eNWIq2gAKpS0BhJkxFSkU8aQAKdHESDTFYCQBKUEkAPiVraGheSGtFOmQPE2QcUwARSkgiTJx-aFISZVUAHkDFSGQ9DRlnVIjjQIwPUMsKDhwAEgBBOy0sWlqg4bDWjw7DAlTERI0qBenZ7QXB4JHV9s7QADJZGnqSEgA5FUoAfg053T1nA03ZY3YOGsWEUoCiMWSaVAqyGITCoDuDWeqkkMmiCRIADpEQ9kcIAD741gAE0q1WgOBYzlkmNp6Ik1OAqR4rncnjwAHV5ughMSAEwpYqlCpVGp1BpNSgRXwBJZwnCJHiIECgCYAUQAHkI6GqsIwsKAALSaUywTLEhFBeq6Yh2M14PKkjohC30kiINleIiC5pcog8yj80BMoA):

```
function withDefaultClassname<Config: {}>(
      Component: React$AbstractComponent<Config, *>
    ): React$AbstractComponent<Config & {className?: string}, *> {
      return (props) => <Component className={props.className || 'default'} {...props} />;
    }
```

Spread operators is better to use for [merging exact types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types).